# С помощью Jsoup спарсить данные из определенной родительской ветки

Tags: java, android, парсер, jsoup

[image: Tree]

При парсинге страницы  в Андроид приложение (пользую последнюю версию либ от Jsoup.org), выбираю только дочерние элементы(Выбираются все элементы, которые на схеме выделены розовым), а можно как нибудь выбрать сначала дочерние элементы с первого родителя, а потом только со второго и т.д.Как это примерно реализовать?

Comment: Очевидный вариант сначала выбрать родителей, а потом для каждого родителя выбирать детей чем плох?

Comment: zRrr, а можно по подробней, как это реализовать, как я понял вы имеете в виду: считать родителей, а потом их детей, можно примерный код? На словах понятно, а как в коде не знаю, или мб ссылку где пишется про это

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидное решение с выбором родительских элементов и последующим поиском детей в них.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<html>"
            + "<head>"
            + "  <title>Try jsoup</title>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "  <div id=\"parent1\">"
            + "    <p>child1.1</p>"
            + "    <p>child1.2</p>"
            + "    <p>child1.3</p>"
            + "  </div>"
            + "  <div id=\"parent2\">"
            + "    <p>child2.1</p>"
            + "    <p>child2.2</p>"
            + "    <p>child2.3</p>"
            + "  </div>"
            + "  <div id=\"parent3\">"
            + "    <p>child3.1</p>"
            + "    <p>child3.2</p>"
            + "    <p>child3.3</p>"
            + "  </div>"
            + "  <div id=\"parent4\">"
            + "  </div>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );

    Elements parents = doc.select( "div" ); // выбор родителей
    System.out.printf( // можно выбрать элемент по индексу 
            "parent[%d]: %s#%s%n", 2, 
            parents.get( 2 ).tagName(), parents.get( 2 ).id() );

    for ( Element parent : parents ) {
        System.out.printf( "parent: %s#%s%n", parent.tagName(), parent.id() );
        for ( Element child : parent.select( "p" ) ) { // выбор внутри родителя
            System.out.println( child.text() );
        }
    }
}
```

Выведет:

```
parent[2]: div#parent3
parent: div#parent1
child1.1
child1.2
child1.3
parent: div#parent2
child2.1
child2.2
child2.3
parent: div#parent3
child3.1
child3.2
child3.3
parent: div#parent4
```

Используя [псевдоселектор](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) `:has(selector)`, можно выбрать только те `<div>`, в которых есть `<p>`:

```
Elements parents = doc.select( "div:has(p)" );
```

Тогда в выдачу не попадет `#parent4`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!